# Open file from server using StreamReader

Tags: c#, file, url, path, streamreader

i´m trying to open a file that is allocated on server using streamreader and give me an error.

Code:

```
string path = @"localhost:91/Files/1/Documents/7d08d443-402f-47c7-978f-9f5069903019.csv";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
```

ERROR: The given path's format is not supported

Comment: Are you trying to do that over HTTP?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jim. Yes i am. I can't?

Comment: If you want to access a file over HTTP, you'll need to use `WebClient.DownloadFile` to download it and then open it. Or you can use `HttpWebRequest` to make the request and open a `StreamReader` on the response stream.

Answer (score 1):

To get a stream representing a file downloaded from a web server you need something like this

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://servername:91/path/to/file.csv");
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
  using (Stream stm = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    //use response
  }
}
```

Obviously replacing the url with your URL.

Old answer for opening a local file is below.
You should use a UNC path of the form

```
\\servername\sharename\path\to\file.csv
```

On a seperate point, when you create the StreamReader you should use a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block to ensure the streamreader gets closed promptly.

Comment: I'm confused sorry, i'm new here. I need to make a test and read a.csv file already saved in server folder and i have the location of the file, indicated in the question (localhost:91/....). 
My problem is that path is in incorrect format because the port specified in path variable. How i resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your URL didn't include http, I assumed you were trying to access the file on a windows fileserver, not access it on a web server.  I've amended my answer to include an example for accessing the file directly from the web server.